# Passing a js array of different elements to php for validate and store in mysql database?

Tags: javascript, php

this is my js file

data stored in questions[] array

**questions = [name,email,phone number,college,year....................]**

```
var questions = [
  {question:"Your Name?"},
  {question:"What's your email?", pattern: /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/},
  {question:"College name?"},
  {question:"Present Year/Semister?"},
  {question:"Phone number?", type: "number"},
  {question:"Ambitional/Professional"},
  {question:"Dreamed big for yourself? (Yes/No)"},
  {question:"Goal or Dream"},
  {question:"Will you use your oppurtunity? (Yes/No)"},
  {question:"How do you know about US"},
  {question:"Create your password", type: "password"}
]

;(function(){

  var tTime = 100  // transition transform time from #register in ms
  var wTime = 200  // transition width time from #register in ms
  var eTime = 1000 // transition width time from inputLabel in ms

  // init
  // --------------
  var position = 0

  putQuestion()

  progressButton.addEventListener('click', validate)
  inputField.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
    transform(0, 0) // ie hack to redraw
    if(e.keyCode == 13) validate()
  })

  // functions
  // --------------

  // load the next question
  function putQuestion() {
    inputLabel.innerHTML = questions[position].question
    inputField.value = ''
    inputField.type = questions[position].type || 'text'  
    inputField.focus()
    showCurrent()
  }

  // when all the questions have been answered
  function done() {

    // remove the box if there is no next question
    register.className = 'close'

    // add the h1 at the end with the welcome text
    var h1 = document.createElement('h1')
    h1.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Welcome to THE99C ' + questions[0].value + '!'))
    setTimeout(function() {
      register.parentElement.appendChild(h1)     
      setTimeout(function() {h1.style.opacity = 1}, 50)
    }, eTime)

  }

  // when submitting the current question
  function validate() {

    // set the value of the field into the array
    questions[position].value = inputField.value

    // check if the pattern matches
    if (!inputField.value.match(questions[position].pattern || /.+/)) wrong()
    else ok(function() {

      // set the progress of the background
      progress.style.width = ++position * 100 / questions.length + 'vw'

      // if there is a new question, hide current and load next
      if (questions[position]) hideCurrent(putQuestion)
      else hideCurrent(done)

    })

  }

  // helper
  // --------------

  function hideCurrent(callback) {
    inputContainer.style.opacity = 0
    inputProgress.style.transition = 'none'
    inputProgress.style.width = 0
    setTimeout(callback, wTime)
  }

  function showCurrent(callback) {
    inputContainer.style.opacity = 1
    inputProgress.style.transition = ''
    inputProgress.style.width = '100%'
    setTimeout(callback, wTime)
  }

  function transform(x, y) {
    register.style.transform = 'translate(' + x + 'px ,  ' + y + 'px)'
  }

  function ok(callback) {
    register.className = ''
    setTimeout(transform, tTime * 0, 0, 10)
    setTimeout(transform, tTime * 1, 0, 0)
    setTimeout(callback,  tTime * 2)
  }

  function wrong(callback) {
    register.className = 'wrong'
    for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++) // shaking motion
      setTimeout(transform, tTime * i, (i%2*2-1)*20, 0)
    setTimeout(transform, tTime * 6, 0, 0)
    setTimeout(callback,  tTime * 7)
  }

}())
```

Help me... to send questions array to php file for checking and storing in MYSQL database.

Php file need to take input from each array indexed value into variables.

Comment: you can use ajax for submitting values into PHP and then store into DB

Comment: Create an HTML form, load those `questions` in that form, Write AJAX for submitting the data to PHP file, said PHP file inserts those questions in tables

Comment: Please convert your post to a question. SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ajax in javascript you can achieve this add the following code after your code

```
$.ajax({
  data: 'questions =' + questions ,
  url: 'url_where_php_is_located.php', // post your values to php 
  method: 'POST', // or GET
  success: function(msg) {
    alert(msg);
  }
});
```

in your PHP you can access data as

```
$str = json_decode($_POST['str'], true);
```

and you can do all your DB operations inside PHP as usual and send response

send a response to javascript using

```
echo "Added to DB";
```

this will send give the alert in ajax response

```
success: function(msg) {
    alert(msg); // Added to DB
  }
```

on your request adding PHP file to store data

```
<?php
$str = json_decode($_POST['str'], true);
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO Your_Table(answer)
VALUES ('$str[0]')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: this is not school my dear, we can help on issues not what you expect, add your logic into it and loop through it

Comment: Thanks, it works but when i'm submitting a error occured: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pattern' of undefined"

Comment: i dont understand your point, where does this error occur while executing ? can your process of execution ?